# Issue with code running regardless

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a html button

```
<input class="showOptions" type="button" style="width:100%" value="<%= (PRCDMU) %>" onclick="programSelector(this.value)" />
```

That calls some JavaScript

```
    function programSelector(value){
    var origin = document.getElementById('origin').value();

    if(origin === ""){
            $( "#popup" ).dialog( "open" ); 
    }
    if(origin === "Product Specification"){
        url = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + value; 
        window.location.href = url;
    }elseif(origin === "Future Requirements Forecast")
        url = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPRF.rpgle?ProductCode=' + value;    
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

However a part of this process is a pop up in Jquery.

```
     $(".showOptions").click(function(){
var $self = this.value;
$( "#popup" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 465,
            draggable: true,
            buttons: {
            "Product Specification": function() { 
            window.location.href = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + $self;  
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
                "Future Requirements Forecast": function() { //cancel
                window.location.href = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPRF.rpgle?ProductCode=' + $self;    
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }

});
```

});

The issue I have is that the popup is appearing regarless, whereas It is only meant to appear depending on the contents of the origin variable, if it's empty the pop up should work

EDIT:

origin is displayed on a html page.

```
    <div align="left">Please click on the<strong> Product Code</strong>, to use it within the <div class="style1" id="origin"><%= (origin) %> program. </div></div>
```

Comment: incomplete sample code, eh? where is the element with `id='origin'`?

Comment: If it pleases you, It comes through the URL

Comment: Matt, `document.getElementById('origin').value` is used to get the value from an html element. In your edit, your button references a querystring (GET) parameter/variable. are we to presume that on the page/resource `http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMSRPROD.rpgle?` there is an element with the `id='origin'`?

Comment: Why are you saying "We"? You haven't said anything useful

Comment: you know, you're pretty disrespect for someone asking for help.. you put up a poor, incomplete question.. and your first edit raised additional inquries.. `div` elements do not have `value` properties.. you're going to need to need to use `innerText`.. which is case and point why you should post a complete code sample that reproduces the problem.. But you're correct in that your immediate issue was not related.. you SHOULD have been opening two dialog boxes, but the first one was failing due to syntax issue `.value()`.. and it would have failed regardless due to the element being a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax Error in `.value()`

It should be

```
var origin = document.getElementById('origin').value;
```

Instead Of

```
var origin = document.getElementById('origin').value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have attached both onclick and click events on the same button:

take out this code from click event and add [`autoOpen to false;`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen)

```
$( "#popup" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 465,
                draggable: true,
                buttons: {
                "Product Specification": function() { 
                window.location.href = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + $self;  
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                    "Future Requirements Forecast": function() { //cancel
                    window.location.href = 'http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPRF.rpgle?ProductCode=' + $self;    
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }

    });

        $(".showOptions").click(function(){
           //based on the value open the dialog.
        }
```

and remove this `onclick="programSelector(this.value)"`